# Two Definitions of Sub-gaussian Norm

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

I am studying sub-gaussian random variables, and have come across the following two definitions of the sub-gaussian norm $\|X\|_{\psi_2}$ of a sub-gaussian random variable $X$:

1. [Vershynin's *High-Dimensional Probability*](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html) defines
   $$
   \|X\|_{\psi_2}=\inf\{t>0:\mathbb{E}\exp(X^2/t^2)\le 2\}.
   $$
2. [Vershynin's *Introduction to the Non-asymptotic Analysis of Random Matrices*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3027) defines
   $$
   \|X\|_{\psi_2}=\sup_{p\ge 1}p^{-1/2}\left(\mathbb{E}|X|^p\right)^{1/p}.
   $$

From Proposition 2.5.2 of [Vershynin's *High-Dimensional Probability*](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html), I know that the two definitions differ from each other by at most an absolute constant factor. My question is: do the two definitions give the exact same norm?

Comment: If they differ by only a constant, then convergence is the same under both norms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define for any subgaussian variable $X$
$$\|X\|_{1}:=\inf\{t>0:\mathbb{E}\exp(X^2/t^2)\le 2\}$$
And
$$\|X\|_{2}:=\sup_{p\ge 1}p^{-1/2}\left(\mathbb{E}|X|^p\right)^{1/p} $$

By the result you cite, we know that there exist two positive constants $c$ and $C$ such that $c\|X\|_{1} \le \|X\|_{2}\le C\|X\|_1 $. Thus I interpret your question as

> Do we have $c=C=1$ ?

**The answer is no** : Consider $X$ to be a Rademacher random variable, i.e. $\mathbb P(X=1) = \mathbb P(X = -1) = \frac 1 2$, such that $X^2 = |X|^p = 1$ almost surely (clearly, $X$ is subgaussian since it is bounded). It then is easy to check that
$$\|X\|_1 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\ln 2}} $$
But
$$\|X\|_2 = 1 $$

---

**Addendum :** The OP asks

> What if we change the definition of $\|\cdot\|_1$ to $$\|X\|_1:=\inf\{t>0:\mathbb{E}\exp(X^2/t^2)\le e\} $$ ?

The answer remains the same : Let $X\sim \text{Bernoulli}(q)$ with $0<q<1$, i.e. $\mathbb P(X=1) = q = 1 - \mathbb P(X=0)$ (I name the parameter $q$ because there is already a $p$ in the definition of $\|\cdot\|_2$).
Now we have $X= X^2 = |X|^p$ almost surely for all $p\ge 1$, and [it is not hard to check](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Moment_Generating_Function_of_Bernoulli_Distribution) that
$$\|X\|_1=\inf\left\{t>0:e^{1/t^2}\le \frac{e - (1 -q )}{q}\right\} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\ln (e - (1-q)) - \ln(q)}}$$
And
$$\|X\|_2= \sup_{p\ge 1}p^{-1/2}q^{1/p} $$

I'm pretty sure that the above supremum can be found in closed form by elementary calculus, but I'm feeling a bit lazy right now, so instead you can use your favourite computing tool to find out that for $q=1/2$ :
$$\|X\|_1 > \|X\|_2 $$

You can actually see (or at least convince yourself) from this argument that changing the $2$ or $e$ in the definition of $\|\cdot\|_1$ to any other positive number will not change the conclusion : $\|\cdot\|_1 $ and $\|\cdot\|_2 $ are **not** equal.

Comment: Thanks! What if $\|X\|_1=\inf\{t>0:\mathbb{E}\exp(X^2/t^2)\le e\}$?

Comment: @Marlovo the conclusion remains the same, see my edit.

Comment: @Marlovo which books did you find the definition of $||X||_1$ in that way?

Comment: @Pipnap It's from [Vershynin's *High-Dimensional Probability*](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html).